# bikeshedding CSS3 property alternative?

Tags: css, w3c, polyfills, shim

Is there any alternative for `bikeshedding` CSS3 property? It doesn't seem to be supported yet.

Comment: This property indeed exists: http://www.w3.org/blog/CSS/2011/03/15/resolutions_152 O_o

Comment: It's been renamed again, but it's not in the `css3-text` document I linked.  http://www.xanthir.com/feed/public-css-commits/?t=2011-06-03T13:58:11+00:00

Comment: Is it a general question or are you trying to do something with this property?

Comment: I am specifically interested in `bikeshedding: collapse;`.

Comment: I would like to have some of what the CSS guys must be smoking at their meetings.

Comment: @Guy: What specifically are you trying to do with `bikeshedding: collapse`?

Comment: The problem occurs when there is `<inline element />\r\n<inline element \>`. The line-break between the two inline elements creates a white space, which I am trying to remove. `bikeshedding` supposed to do that. Strange name, `bikeshedding`, eh?

Comment: @Guy: I'm aware of a few ways to work around that. Can you make a [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/) showing a specific situation? Even if it is just two `span` elements. I just want to be sure we're on the same page here, thanks.

Comment: See the space between two DIVs http://jsfiddle.net/F3Mdd/

Comment: Name related to  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parkinson%27s_law_of_triviality ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove the space between inline-block elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-to-remove-the-space-between-inline-block-elements)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The white-space property**

In CSS3, The `white-space` property is a shorthand for the `white-space-collapsing` (I guess `bikeshedding` means they don't know what to call it yet) and `text-wrap` properties. The `white-space` property is a CSS 2.1 property supported by most browsers and there are two values for it that collapse new lines:

1. `normal` (The initial value).
2. `nowrap`

**But what does collapsing line feed characters mean?**

According to CSS 2.1:

> If 'white-space' is set to 'normal' or
>   'nowrap', linefeed characters are
>   transformed for rendering purpose into
>   one of the following characters: a
>   space character, a zero width space
>   character (U+200B), or no character
>   (i.e., not rendered), according to
>   UA-specific algorithms based on the
>   content script.

According to CSS 3:

> A zero width space before or after a
>   white space sequence containing a
>   newline causes the entire sequence of
>   white space to collapse into a zero
>   width space.

Reality:

Most browsers transform line feed characters into a **space**. So what you really want is to set the `white-space-collapsing` property to `discard` not `collapse` or to `collapse` and then add a zero width space character before the line break.

**What to do till browser support**

Remove white-space from your HTML document:

```
<span>A</span>
<span>B</span>
```

To:

```
<span>A</span><span>B</span>
```

Or:

```
<span>A</span><span>
    B</span>
```

Comment: Actually, the second option presented would still result in a space between the A and the B. Just FYI. Good info though, thanks! ;)

Comment: You can move the whitespace inside the tags for readability: `<span>A</span [linebreak] ><span>B</span`

Answer (score 11):

There's always the most obvious fix, which is to simply remove the whitespace in the HTML:

http://jsfiddle.net/F3Mdd/1/ - it's really easy, and it just works. From this:

```
<div>a</div>
<div>a</div>
```

to this:

```
<div>a</div><div>a</div>
```

Here's a more detailed [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-to-remove-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/5078297#5078297).

***To be honest, I always just remove the whitespace...***

Answer (score 2):

Another approach is simply to wait for this CSS3 feature and remove the whitespace by Javascript until then.

http://jsfiddle.net/rT4Dy/2/

```
$('[data-bikeshedding="discard"]').each (function () {
  var node = $(this);
  node.html (node.find ('> *').detach ());
});
```

Comment: This answer should be the correct answer! I love it.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you mean the [`text-spacing`](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-text/#text-spacing) property.

As far as I can tell, [there isn't a lot of support](http://caniuse.com/#search=text-).

Comment: The second link doesn't mention text-spacing, so I'm not sure how you came to the conclusion in the link text.