# Hide elements, that overflows a fixed width element

Tags: html, css

Consider the following ...

http://roosteronacid.com/viewport.png

Here's three elements, with only one element shown (left-most). Is this possible? I've tried something along the lines of this ...

```
<div id="container">
    <div></div>
    <div>I overflow the container, so I should be hidden</div>
    <div>I also overflow the container, so I should be hidden</div>
</div>

#container {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 300px;
}

#container div {
    float: left;
    width: 300px;
}
```

... But I can't get it to work without specifying a fixed height. Which is something I don't want to. The height of an element has to be dynamic and grow according its content.

*Note: this has to be a iOS Safari compatible.*

Comment: It won't auto grow height with `height: auto` (default I believe)?

Comment: I'm confused - the inner divs are expanding the outer container, but you don't want them to? It should be noted that the overflow: hidden is how you expand the containing div to contain inner, floated divs.

Comment: http://roosteronacid.com/viewport.png 404s please re-upload somewhere more stable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/9Nh7t/

- Replace `float: left`, with `display: inline-block`.
- To prevent wrapping, add `white-space: nowrap` on the parent element.

To get rid of "the gaps" ([visible here](http://jsfiddle.net/9Nh7t/1/), for example), the easiest fix is to remove the whitespace from your HTML: http://jsfiddle.net/9Nh7t/2/

Comment: Wow! That was fast! I'd like to format my source with indents and spaces. Is there any way to remove the white-space in-between the elements (rendered) without having to truncate my source?

Comment: Sure: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6350218/bikeshedding-css3-property-alternative/6351697#6351697