# HTML image bottom alignment inside DIV container

Tags: html, css, image, alignment, spacing

I have a div tag with a fixed height.  Most of the images have the same height and width.

I want to align the images at the bottom of the div so that they are nicely arranged.  Here is what I have so far:

```
<div id="randomContainer">
    <div id="imageContainer">
        <img src="1.png" alt=""/>
        <img src="2.png" alt=""/>
        <img src="3.png" alt=""/>
        <img src="4.png" alt=""/>
    </div>
    <div id="navigationContainer">
        <!-- navigation stuff -->
    </div>
</div>
```

The CSS looks like:

```
div#imageContainer {
    height: 160px;  
    vertical-align: bottom;
    display: table-cell;
}
```

I managed to align the images at the bottom with `display: table-cell` and the `vertical-align: bottom` css attributes.

Is there a cleaner way as displaying the div as table-cell and aligning the images at the bottom of the DIV tag?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

This is your code: http://jsfiddle.net/WSFnX/

Using `display: table-cell` is fine, provided that you're aware that it won't work in IE6/7. Other than that, it's safe: [Is there a disadvantage of using `display:table-cell`on divs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6307934/is-there-a-disadvantage-of-using-displaytable-cellon-divs)

To fix the space at the bottom, add `vertical-align: bottom` to the actual `img`s:

http://jsfiddle.net/WSFnX/1/

Removing the space between the images boils down to this: [bikeshedding CSS3 property alternative?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6350218/bikeshedding-css3-property-alternative/6351697#6351697)

So, here's a demo with the whitespace removed in your HTML: http://jsfiddle.net/WSFnX/4/

Answer (score 67):

Set the parent div as `position:relative` and the inner element to `position:absolute; bottom:0`

Comment: This only works if you set the height of the container.

Answer (score 27):

Flexboxes can accomplish this by using `align-items: flex-end;` with `display: flex;` or `display: inline-flex;`

```
div#imageContainer {
    height: 160px;  
    align-items: flex-end;
    display: flex;

    /* This is the default value, so you only need to explicitly set it if it's already being set to something else elsewhere. */
    /*flex-direction: row;*/
}
```

[JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/Ironsmith/42td0e9r/6/)

[CSS-Tricks has a good guide for flexboxes](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: I think you don't need the `flex-direction: column;` part; works well for me!

Comment: Buggy support in IE11, no support for earlier IE versions, according to https://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

Comment: Since you changed the flex-direction from the default of `row` to `column`, the `align-items` property now acts to align the children HORIZONTALLY. You should either remove `flex-direction` property from the above code OR change `align-items` to `justify-content`

Comment: Somehow this answer is messed up: the once existing `flex-direction: column;` never works but had to be `flex-direction: row;` and the example on jsfiddle never includes the flex-properties but `display: table-cell`. Nevertheless this answer solved my issue, therefore up-vote.

Comment: Stange @David, thanks for pointing that out. Looks like JSFiddle forgot my actual fiddle, then someone clicked on the link and created another fiddle overwriting mine? I'll update the JSFiddle.

Comment: Also note @David, `flex-direction: row;` is the default value, so unless some other css sets it, you can leave it blank and it'll behave as `flex-direction: row;`.

Comment: @Daniel yes you're right `flex-direction: row;` is the default and can be omitted.

Answer (score 10):

**`<div>`** with some proportions

```
div {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

**`<img>`**'s with their own proportions

```
img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: auto; /* to keep proportions */
  height: auto; /* to keep proportions */
  max-width: 100%; /* not to stand out from div */
  max-height: 100%; /* not to stand out from div */
  margin: auto auto 0; /* position to bottom and center */
}
```

Comment: This solution is regrettable very error-prone when the width of the outer container / viewport is changing.