# Centering content of div with display: table-cell used to bottom align

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I'm trying to create a centered div with the content of that div (a few images) bottom aligned.  Bottom aligning the content is already a tricky issue that I've resolved (using [HTML image bottom alignment inside DIV container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6520940/image-bottom-alignment-inside-div-container)).  However, the solution removed the centering of the div.

The way I was centering was using `display: inline-block;`
Original, before bottom aligning content:
http://jsfiddle.net/5NuBD/

The fix to bottom align was adding
`display: table-cell;vertical-align: bottom;`
New, with bottom aligned content, which is no longer centered:
http://jsfiddle.net/KurpZ/

I'm looking for a centered div that is also bottom aligned.  It seems these two solutions are incompatible.

Comment: I misunderstood your question and thought you wanted to vertically center the container of your images (images still being at the bottom of this container) inside `#wrapper` so my answer with http://jsfiddle.net/KurpZ/1/ is void.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up setting the css to a fixed width, as suggested by Chris.  I then used jquery to sum the widths of each image and manually set the [`.width()`](http://api.jquery.com/width/) after the page loaded.  This works.

Answer (score 1):

If the div can be a fixed width :

```
#wrapper {
    text-align:center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 230px;
}
```

Comment: That's frustrating.  I need the width to be dynamic.